# Degree of randomness in entropy and true randomness

Tags: random, cryptography, terminology, entropy

I'm finding mixed answers when it comes to **how random *true random numbers* really are**.

Let's say we want a random number for use in cryptography. If we gather entropy from mouse movement and other sources; is this not true random data? How could one possibly predict or recreate the entropy created by these sources (unless someone is spying on this device)?

Another example is measuring radiation and turning it into entropy. Algorithms can extract the randomness of data streams, but can they really predict the exact pattern of radiation that happened in that specific instance of entropy gathering?

Is the problem that too little entropy is generated, and the cryptographic function can be reversed by brute forcing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the problem that too little entropy is generated, and the
>   cryptographic function can be reversed by brute forcing?

Well there is no problems if you use **strong** crypto **correctly** and supply **good** random numbers. Any crypto can be reversed by brute forcing, this is the default case. Straight brute force on good encryption is trillions-of-years long in average, so we basically write it off as unbreakable. Weakness in algorithm, its usage, or quality of random numbers allows attacker to reverse encryption faster than brute force method.

> If we gather entropy from mouse movement and other sources; is this
>   not true random data? How could one possibly predict or recreate the
>   entropy created by these sources (unless someone is spying on this
>   device)?

As a slightly contrived example: we gather randomness from the last bit of the mouse position data. Some manufacturers use expensive mouse controllers that support full 32 bit precision, but others use cheaper controllers with lower resolution that gives us 24 significant bits, and last 8 are always zero.

> Another example is measuring radiation and turning it into entropy.

Now this is a better example, here is where the **true** randomness comes in. True randomness, as I understand it, refers to data, that is a result of a process, that is believed to be completely unpredictable. Mouse movements are caused by muscle contractions, which are predictable (given tons of info about atoms in your body which is impossible to collect or process). Radioactive decay is a result of quantum process, which is inherently unpredictable, irregardless of the amount of data or processing power we have.

Here’s a real world example of weak RNG ruining good crypto: your OS implements CSPRNG (Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator). It usually gets its randomness from timing of network packets, HDD seek times, keypresses and mouse movements, things like that. Now let’s imagine server with an SSD, that’s just booted and has to generate cryptographic key. It hasn’t had any network traffic and no keyboard or mouse is connected. Now that’s a bad situation, and CSPRNG might output guessable random numbers.

There’s a bunch of (somewhat flawed) ways to prevent this from happening, including storing last state of CSPRNG on shutdown and reloading it on boot, using temperature sensors on processor itself to get some of the heat entropy, or CSPRNG not returning random number until it gets enough entropy from its sources.

In all honesty, random numbers are rarely a source of failures, most are due to incorrect usage of a cryptographic algorithm or usage of a known weak algorithm by the programmer, hence “do not write your own crypto” is a common proverb.